# Find $h'(7)$ when given $h(x) = f(x)/g(x)$, and the values of $f(7),g(7),f'(7),g'(7)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

**Full Question**

> Let $f(7)=0, f'(7)=14, g(7)=1, g'(7)=1/7$. Find $h'(7)$ if $h(x)=f(x)/g(x)$.

This kind of problem has been showing up in practice questions a lot recently, the problem, is there is no example of this in my notes and I'm lost.

If someone could maybe set me down the right path process wise, I think I can get it.

Comment: Do you know the "quotient rule"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with what's known as the quotient rule. Let $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$. Then

$$f'(x)=\frac{g'(x)h(x)-g(x)h'(x)}{[h(x)]^2}$$

If we substitute the values given, we get

$$h'(7)=\frac{f'(7)g(7)-f(7)g'(7)}{[g(7)]^2}$$

$$=\frac{(14)(1)-(0)(\frac{1}{7})}{1^2}$$
$$=14$$

Comment: Thank you! I know the quotient rule, but never thought about using it for this problem. Now it is so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

$h'(x)=\frac{(f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x))}{(g(x))^2}$

Comment: You should probably add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The quotient rule is really a combined application of the chain rule and the product rule:

$\begin{eqnarray}
h(x) & = & \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = f(x) \times [g(x)]^{-1} \\
h'(x) & = & \frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x) \times [g(x)]^{-1}\right) \\
& = & \frac{d}{dx}f(x) \times [g(x)]^{-1} + f(x) \times \frac{d}{dx}[g(x)]^{-1} \\
& = & f'(x)[g(x)]^{-1} + f(x) \times \left(-g'(x)[g(x)]^{-2} \right) \\
& = & \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)}-\frac{f(x)g'(x)}{[g(x)]^2} \\
& = & \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{[g(x)]^2}
\end{eqnarray}$